# Minting and spending from the same script in a single transaction

Tags: plutus, lucid, aiken

I have a state NFT token locked in an hybrid script written in Aiken. I want to :

- spend this NFT state to the script itself ( with a new datum which stores the new issuance state )
- mint tokens I want to distribute. ( the state NFT is designed to
  store the minting issuance numbers ).

Is it possible ? I have coded my offchain code with lucid, but I can't do both minting and
spending... But I can't figure why it wouldn't be possible to do both in the same transaction.